# Creating a pod/container in kubernetes - how to copy a bunch of files into it

Tags: kubernetes

Sorry if this is a noob question:

I am creating a pod in a kubernetes cluster using a pod defintion yaml file.

This pod defines just one container. I'd like to ... copy a few files to a particular directory in the container.

sort of like in docker-compose:

```
volumes:
      - ./testHelpers/certs:/var/private/ssl/certs
```

Is it possible to do that at this point (point of defining the pod?)

If not, what could my alternatives be?

PS - I understand that the sample from docker-compose is very different since this maps local directory to a directory in container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use volumes in pod definition. 
[Initialize the pod before the container runs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/)

Apart from this, you can also use ConfigMap to store certs and other config files you needed and than can access them in the container as volumes.
[More details here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume)

Comment: you should not use configMaps to store certs. That is what are secrets for.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a config map, you can do it from files or a directory.

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=configuration/
```

And then mount the config map as directory:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmap-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: busybox
      volumeMounts:
        - name: my-config
          mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: my-config
      configMap:
        name: my-config
```

Comment: Hmm... would this actually create files in the container's FS?

Comment: No. The kubelet uses volume mount into the container. Use 'docker inspect' on the host to see this